# How to enable MALLOC_PROTECT_BEFORE in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, simulator

After switching on some debug options in Xcode, I get this output:

```
GuardMalloc[Roadcast-4010]: free: magic is 0x0000090b, not 0xdeadbeef.
GuardMalloc[Roadcast-4010]: free: header magic value at 0x43f49bf0, for block 0x43f49c00-0x43f50000, has been trashed by a buffer underrun.
GuardMalloc[Roadcast-4010]: Try running with MALLOC_PROTECT_BEFORE to catch this error immediately as it happens.
```

How do I switch on `MALLOC_PROTECT_BEFORE`?

**UPDATE**:

What `MALLOC_PROTECT_BEFORE` does, is documented at [Mac Developer Library > Guard_Malloc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/Guard_Malloc.3.html):

> libgmalloc's behavior can be changed with several additional
>   environment variables:
>
> MALLOC_PROTECT_BEFORE
>
> If this flag is set, then libgmalloc tries harder to detect buffer
>   underruns.  Specifically, libgmalloc places the start of the allocated
>   buffer at the beginning of a virtual memory page, then protects the page
>   before.  Buffer underruns then cause an error.  The behavior without
>   this variable set is to place the end of the buffer at the end of the
>   last page of the allocation, and protect the page after.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To enable MALLOC_PROTECT_BEFORE in Xcode, in the Xcode Menu go to

Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme...

and then in the page which pops up, go to Arguments and under Environment Variables, add `MALLOC_PROTECT_BEFORE` and give it the value `1`. You can see this in Screenshot 1:

[image: Screenshot 1: adding MALLOC_PROTECT_BEFORE]

To make this actually being used, now click on Diagnostics and tickmark "Enable Guard Malloc", as shown in Scrrenshot 2:

[image: Screenshot 2: Enable Guard Malloc]

Then click OK and it's done.

To test whether detecting buffer underruns now works, use the following code:

```
    int* allocated = malloc(1024);

    printf("If this is the last line printed, then MALLOC_PROTECT_BEFORE is enabled and buffer underruns are detected.\n");

    int value = allocated[-5]; // fails if MALLOC_PROTECT_BEFORE is set AND activated

    printf("The value read from unallocated memory space is %i.\n", value);
    printf("If this line is printed, then MALLOC_PROTECT_BEFORE is NOT enabled and buffer underruns can occur unnoticed.\n");

    free(allocated);
    allocated = NULL;
```